# Formula for trying to get the length of an isometric shadow?

Tags: c#, wpf, isometric

I'm creating a canvas with isometric blocks on it.  What I want to do is cast a shadow from the blocks.  I currently have a version of it working, but the shadow appears a lot longer than it should.  I was wondering if there was any formula to work out how to cast a shadow properly.

What I would like is the shadow to be slightly shorter than the height.

[image: So far]
<sub>(source: [net84.net](http://peterfleming.net84.net/Untitled2.png))</sub>

Regards
Peter

Comment: Do you have coordinates of all elements (including light source's vector) in the Euclidean space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula?

Its trigonometry:

The light source vector is side `c` of a triangle, your block the `a` side.

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

Or the length of the shadow being `b`

```
b^2 = c^2 - a^2
```

or

```
b = square root of (c^2 - a^2)
```

PS this is predicated on the angle of a & b being 90 degrees, aka your block stands straight up.  Otherwise you'll need to use the angle between a & c and then use cos, sin and or tangent to figure the length of side b.  I forget exactly, but you can ask here: https://math.stackexchange.com/

See this calculator: http://www.carbidedepot.com/formulas-trigright.asp